# How to clone my Lucid (10.04) + root as an image for further re-installation?

Tags: clone, cd-image

How to clone my OS + it's root as an image (without size limitation) and then for example writing it on a dual layered DVD? I used Remastersys but it issues the size of the output image and then aborts.

I'm trying to make an unlimited image with capability of re-installation using normal boot.

I tried Clonezilla a little bit, but I'm not sure it really helps. The problem is that I want unlimited size and I think (iso) is defined to not exceed 4.7GB.

I really am confused and desperate. If you know a solution please share.

Comment: I think Clonezilla es the way to go. I've never used to clone a whole OS but it should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try REMASTERSYS. It's help me a lot with backup the whole system including your home folder data (Music, Pictures, etc). It's also creating LiveCD/LiveUSB mode,. Hope this help you :)

http://www.remastersys.com/